# Remove leading character in Datagridview value and get output to other column c# windows application

Tags: c#

I want to know that how to remove leading characters in DataGridView value and get output to other column c# windows application. For example I have values in cell [6], 2020-03-18, 2020-02-13, 2020-02-12 like this. I need to output only 18, 13, 12 into cell [16]. Please help on this.

```
 private void Btnshortdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < DataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {                             
            DataGridViewRow row = DataGridView1.Rows[i];
            row.Cells[16].Value = DataGridView1.Columns[6].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd";                               

        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired value like this. You can split the string and then take the substring, then add to a list and then join the list to make the string.

```
string str = "2020-03-18, 2020-02-13, 2020-02-12";
string[] arr = str.Split(',');
List<string> ls = new List<string>();
foreach(string a in arr)
{
    ls.Add(a.Substring(a.LastIndexOf('-') + 1));
}

string output  = string.Join(",", ls);
```

Comment: Vivek, how to solve this in DataGridView, i need to get output to new column in DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only a date in a cell:

```
private void Btnshortdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < DataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {                             
            DataGridViewRow row = DataGridView1.Rows[i];
            row.Cells[16].Value = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString().Substring(8);
        }
     }
```

But if you have all those dates in a cell:

```
private string Function(string str)
        {
           // string str = "2020-03-18, 2020-02-13, 2020-02-12"; 
            string[] tmp = str.Split(", ".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            for (int i=0;i<tmp.Length;i++)
            {
                tmp[i] = tmp[i].Substring(8);
            }
            return string.Join(", ", tmp);//=>"18, 13, 12" 
        }
private void Btnshortdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < DataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {                             
                DataGridViewRow row = DataGridView1.Rows[i];
                row.Cells[16].Value = Function(row.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
            }
         }
```

However, you could use the function in the first case too, but is simplier without.